# Help me to optimize animation in this project

Tags: animation, optimization

I have already watched several videos on how to optimize projects in blender, but it still takes me several minutes to render 1 frame, and the entire project will take at least 200 minutes to render. This is norm?
I left the project file below in Google Drive:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qi_O7eSEoPYKHSHjdqTzvsfYx9LjI9U6/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: You could decrease the Light Bounces total to 1 instead of 3, limit the sampling to 20 instead of 50, or even Time Limit of 5 seconds instead of 0, I can’t barely see a difference

Comment: the shaders seem to be very heavy (at least for little integrated graphics chips). With a simple shader that doesn't use this *Node Group* the render only takes 1/3 of the time in my test. Consider baking texture maps, the outputs of this *Node Group*.